# Using web-config in a folder then how can I add authentication with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, asp.net-web-api2

I tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="admin" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".js" type="System.Web.Compilation.ForceCopyBuildProvider"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

However when a non-authenticated user requests a .js file in the directory where this web-config is placed then the file is served up. Is there something that I am missing? I want the file to be available only to users with the admin role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line of code in the web config file

```
<deny users="*"/>
```

just below

```
<allow roles="admin" />
```

Comment: can you click on code so your answer shows up. thanks

Comment: I tried the change that you suggested however all .js files in that directory still get served. Could there be anything else that I am missing?

Comment: @billah77, you shouldn't edit the solution into the question, I've edited it into your answer instead (lines of code need to be indented by 4 spaces so that it gets formatted as code)